# I'm having problems with MySQL constraints

Tags: mysql, constraints

I'm having some trouble using constraints correctly.

I have three tables, 'item', 'store' and 'link_item_store'.
An Item can be in one or many stores, and one or many stores can have an item.
Since this is a many to many relationship, I'm using 'link_item_store' to normalize.

If I delete an item, I have to remove all instancs of that item in the 'link_item_store' table. And the same goes for store. This is my table and it's constraints:

```
CREATE TABLE `link_item_store` (
  `fk_storeID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `fk_itemID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`fk_storeID`,`fk_itemID`),
  KEY `fk_storeID` (`fk_storeID`),
  KEY `fk_itemID` (`fk_itemID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_danish_ci;

ALTER TABLE `link_item_store`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `link_item_store_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_itemID`) REFERENCES `link_item_store (`fk_itemID`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `link_item_store_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_storeID`) REFERENCES `link_item_store` (`fk_storeID`) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

And heres is an example list:

```
fk_storeID, fk_itemID, itemName, storeName
11  7277    item 1  Test store
11  7278    item 2  Test store
11  7280    item 3  Test store
12  7277    item 1  Test store 2
12  7278    item 2  Test store 2
12  7290    item 4  Test store 2
35  7295    item 4  Test store 4
35  7299    item 5  Test store 4
35  7300    item 6  Test store 4
35  7302    item 7  Test store 4
```

My problem is that if I delete 'item 7' from 'item' table, ALL references are deleted from link_item_store. :(

What to do?

**Update:**
By having these two constraints on the table, I'm not able to insert new data to the table. I get the following error message:

```
Unable to query local database <b>Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign 
key constraint fails ( `link_item_store`, CONSTRAINT 
`link_item_store_item_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_storeID`) REFERENCES 
`link_item_store` (`fk_storeID`) ON DELETE CASCADE)</b><br> INSERT INTO 
link_item_store (fk_storeID, fk_itemID) VALUES ('11', '7295')
```

**Update 2 - Solution:**
Michael pointed out to me that the ADD CONSTRAINT didn't look right. On a closer look, I saw that he was right. This is the code that is generated by PhpMuAdmin upon adding constraints:

```
ALTER TABLE `link_item_store` ADD FOREIGN KEY ( `fk_itemID` ) REFERENCES `mydatabase`.`link_item_store` (`fk_itemID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ;
```

As you can see, the foreign key is reffering to itself! This defenetily have to be a bug in PhPMyAdmin.

The solution was to change reference. This works and I no longer have problems adding new records to the table:

```
ALTER TABLE `link_item_store` ADD FOREIGN KEY ( `fk_itemID` ) REFERENCES `mydatabase`.`item` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of your foreign keys seems unusual to me.

Instead of:

```
ADD CONSTRAINT `link_item_store_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_itemID`) REFERENCES `link_item_store` (`fk_itemID`) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Try:

```
 ADD CONSTRAINT `link_item_store_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_itemID`) REFERENCES item (`itemID`) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

(Assuming `itemID` is the name of the correct column on the item table)

Comment: Your right.... this doesn't seem right... but this is the code PhpMyAdmin generates. It generates an foreign key and references itself???: ALTER TABLE `link_item_store` ADD FOREIGN KEY ( `fk_itemID` ) REFERENCES `mydatabase`.`link_item_store` (`fk_itemID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ;

Comment: Thanks Michael for the heads up. I managed to solve this. See updated post above.

Answer (score 1):

If you delete item 7 how can other stores have it?

The behavior you are seeing is referred to as "cascading deletes".  Every row that references a row you delete with an FK is also deleted.  There is also the normal behavior of not allowing the delete, and a "set null" behavior that will change all FKs to the deleted item to NULL.  It sounds like that's what you want.

Here is a [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) talking about the different options.

Comment: Hi Col. There is no point of having rows containint NULL in a link reference table. If I delete an item with ID = 35 from 'item' table, I want to delete all rows in `link_item_store` which has fk_itemID = 35. I thought adding a constraint would do this fir me. I have no clue why it deletes all other rows as well. I've read the chapter on FOREIGN KEY Constraints at MySQL several times, but I'm non the wiser.

Comment: "My problem is that if I delete 'item 7' from 'item' table, ALL references are deleted from link_item_store". I assumed references meant references to the deleted item